# Logging turns off flask terminal output

Tags: python, flask, vscode-debugger

I have a flask app.py, inside the app I have a write_to_db.py script. 
I added logging to a catch-all decorator and now flask does not output any logging to the terminal and my VS Code debugger does not work.

When I look in the error.log file I only see the basic output like:

> Running on http://127.0.0.1:7900/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='eror.log', level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "CRITICAL"))

def catch_all_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            return "LOADED"
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(e)
            logging.exception("STACK TRACE")
            return "FAIL"
```

I need to log the stack trace data and still see it in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You over-written your default STDOUT handler with `logging.basicConfig(filename='eror.log', level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "CRITICAL"))`.

`Running on http://127.0.0.1:7900/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` - you see this because it actually a "print()" output and not a log output.

Here try this:
`logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "CRITICAL"), handlers=[logging.FileHandler("error.log"), logging.StreamHandler()])`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't log to console unless I set the level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "CRITICAL") LOGLEVEL to "DEBUG"

Comment: Your logs are set to log on "INFO" level `logging.info(e)`. When you use `os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "CRITICAL")` LOGLEVEL is probably returned as None and it then gets the "CRITICAL" value (because you set it).